# expression "to catch a chill"

Tags: expressions

Can the expression "to catch a chill" be used informally today or has it already past its peak in usage? I have seen it mentioned referring to people living in the 19th century.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still hear it used occasionally, but much more common nowadays is ***catch a cold***

Answer (score 2):

It's still found in the UK, but mostly, I suspect, in an older generation.